# Variability in runtime of Arrays.sort java

Tags: java, sorting

I am seeing a great variability in run time in the Arrays.sort method used in the context below. I was wondering if this is a common problem, or if something about how I wrote the code is inefficient? The variability is that on some runs on a graph of 100,000,000 nodes the run time will be approximately 10 seconds on one run and 270 seconds on another run on the same graph with the same number of threads.

Edit: My concern is that when I run this usually the code takes between 100-300 seconds, but occasionally runs will only take 10-20 seconds. For example, running on a 100,000,000 node graph using 30 threads (on a 40 core machine), I got 150 seconds one run and then 20 seconds another run. Nothing had changed on the machine (I used top to make sure no one else could be using it), so I'm not sure what could be causing this.

```
public class AdjacencyGraph {

    static Comparator<Node> comp = new Comparator<Node>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Node n1,Node n2){
            return n1.index - n2.index;
        }
    };

    static class Node {
        final int index;
        Node[] neighbors;
        boolean inMIS = false;
       // public final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        Node(int index) {
            super();
            {
            }
            {
            }
            {
            }
            this.index = index;
        }
        void initNeighbors(int degree) {
        neighbors = new Node[degree];
        }
      }

        public static void sort_neighbors(Node n)
        {
            Arrays.sort(n.neighbors,comp);
        }
        Node[] nodes;

public AdjacencyGraph(int n) {
    super();
    {
    }
    {
    }
    {
    }
    nodes = new Node[n];
}

public static void sort_neighbors(Node n)
{
    Arrays.sort(n.neighbors,comp);
}
static AdjacencyGraph readAdjacencyGraph(String file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    if (!"AdjacencyGraph".equals(reader.readLine())) {
        throw new IOException("invalid adjacency graph format");
    }
    int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int m = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int[] offsets = new int[n];
    int[] edges = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        offsets[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        edges[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    }
    final AdjacencyGraph g = new AdjacencyGraph(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        final Node node = new Node(i);
        g.nodes[i] = node;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int startOffset = offsets[i];
        int endOffset = (i == n - 1) ? m : offsets[i + 1];
        g.nodes[i].initNeighbors(endOffset - startOffset);
        for (int j = startOffset; j < endOffset; j++) {
            g.nodes[i].neighbors[j - startOffset] = g.nodes[edges[j]];
        }


    }
    return g;
 }  
 }
    }
```

Next class:

```
public class GraphSortRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private final int start_idx;
    private final int end_idx;
    private AdjacencyGraph.Node[] nodes;

    public GraphSortRunnable(int start, int end, AdjacencyGraph.Node[] nodes)
    {
        this.start_idx = start;
        this.end_idx = end;
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }


    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = this.start_idx; i < this.end_idx; i++)
            AdjacencyGraph.sort_neighbors(nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException
{
    AdjacencyGraph g = AdjacencyGraph.readAdjacencyGraph(args[0]);
    final int NUM_THREADS = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int size = g.nodes.length / NUM_THREADS;

            List<Thread> threads_sort = new ArrayList<Thread>();
            final long start_sort = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
            {
                Runnable task = new GraphSortRunnable(i*size, (i+1)*size, g.nodes);
                Thread worker = new Thread(task);

                worker.setName(String.valueOf(i));
                worker.start();
                threads_sort.add(worker);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
                threads_sort.get(i).join();
            final long end_sort = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("sort time: " + (end_sort - start_sort)+ "milliseconds");
           // do additional work
 }
```

Comment: I added in the rest of readAdjacencyGraph. It reads in graphs in the Adjacency format listed here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pbbs/benchmarks/graphIO.html. wouldn't the time spent in I/O operations not matter, since the time measured is only in the sorting portion? Also, not sure what you mean by "kernel land"?

Comment: How dense is each of the graphs?

Comment: They're very sparse. The most dense graph we are using has roughly 10 edges per node

Comment: I'm wondering if garbage collection or other system-wide effects may be at fault here. Do you have access to a legit Java profiler so that you can time your code using a measure other than just the wall-clock time?

Comment: Have you tried if you get more consistent run-times by using the [`-Xint` VM option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), which disables possible JIT compiler optimizations?

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try -Xint and look into a java profiler